# Is possible to build FATJar OSGi Bundle with dependencies are not OSGify?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, bnd

I have a doubt about Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin (BND) which I could not find a response. I am trying to build a FATJar OSGI Bundle, I mean, I want a JAR file with all dependencies (even transitive dependencies) inside it.

Can I do this which those dependencies that they are not OSGi Bundles?

Comment: Do you have a single OSGi bundle?

Comment: Yes, I want to get a single OSGi Bundle with all dependencies (and theirs transitive) embedded.

Comment: I don't want to know what you like to get. I would like to know if you get dependencies from several OSGi bundles?

Comment: I believe OSGi want you to have separated jar file per artifact. The closest thing you can get is the kar archive or karaf feature repository from apache karaf project. However, by doing so you will need to stick with Karaf all the time.